# TinyMCE Build Errors

Tags: tinymce

I am trying to use tinyMCE for an MVC project on a server with no internet connection. I have downloaded the self-hosted installation file and added the tinymce folder to my project's scripts folder.

The script tag in included in the head section of the layout file. -

```
<script src="path/to/tinymce/js/tinymce.min.js"></script>
```

After that initialization is done with the script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  tinymce.init({
    selector: '#mytextarea'
  });
  </script>
</head>
```

Unfortunately, I am getting lots of build errors (503 errors). Mainly intinymce.d.ts file.

has anyone come across such issue? Could someone kindly help me resolve this issue?

Many Thanks,

Anu

Comment: removing API key fixed the issue

Answer (score 0):

I tried to run this on a machine with internet connection and it works as expected without any problem. So, it is very clear that there are some links in the .ts file that is trying to access through the internet.

Would be great if I can figure it out.

regards,

Anu